# Jenkins job submission via curl and get its build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

How to submit the Jenkins job using curl api and get its buid number ?
Note - i tried with the following api, but its not printing any build number.

`curl -X POST  http://<hostname>:8080/job/<jobname>/build`

Answer (score 0):

**In general, you can't do this**: when you submit (or "trigger") a Jenkins job, this will not necessarily create and start a new build.

When triggering a job, only a *request for starting a new build* will enter the *build queue*. Depending on the availability of suitable executors, the actual build will be created (and started) immediately, later, or never at all. Also, multiple queued requests will normally be "squashed", so several submits will result in the same build number.

Bottom line: this can be done (with the constraints mentioned before), but **it will require additional (Groovy) scripting for tracking the submit request through the build queue until the build will be started** by Jenkins.

Comment: Actually, it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472604/get-jenkins-job-build-id-from-queue-id) to get the build URL after triggering it. The curl command in the OP returns a `Location` header, indicating the associated queue item, which could be polled for queue status and for the build URL.